# Linux shell script to tar.gzip log files older than 1 month grouped by month

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, archive

I have a directory full of various application logs.
Example:

> FailedAudit_20150101_000000.log  FailedAudit_20150209_000000.log 
>   FailedAudit_20150316_000000.log  stats20150116.log  stats20150224.log
>   FailedAudit_20150102_000000.log  FailedAudit_20150210_000000.log 
>   FailedAudit_20150317_000000.log  stats20150117.log  stats20150225.log
>   FailedAudit_20150103_000000.log  RepoV4Error20150227.log

All the logs have timestamp in format YYYYMMDD but also other numbers involved as you can see.

My objective is to write a script that can be run once periodically to go through this directory and do the following:
**For all log files older than 1 month, based on filename timestamp**

- for each months worth of files (30~31 files), tar.gz them into one file
- label the tar.gz file as

> App1_201508.tar.gz <-- contains all 30 log files
>   So format AppnameYYYYMM.tar.gz

The log file application name is static except for the timestamp.

I suppose there is a few ways to do this but I would like to gather ideas from the great minds of stackoverflow to find the simplest way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the third solution for your updated question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOGTYPES=$( ls *log* | sed -rn "s/([0-9]{6})[0-9]{2}.*$/\1/p" | sort -u )

# the sed command, item by item:
#
# s/ search and replace
# ([0-9]{6}) block of 6 digits, and store it
# [0-9]{2} followed by 2 more digits
# .*$ followed by any and all characters until the end of the input
# / replace all of that with
# \1 the first stored block (the 6 digits)
# /p print the output
#
# So this turns FailedAudit_20150101_000000.log into FailedAudit_201501

THIS_MONTH=$(date +%Y%m)
for LOG in $LOGTYPES; do
    MONTH=${LOG: -6} # Last 6 characters of the LOGTYPE are YYYYMM

    if [[ "$MONTH" -lt "$THIS_MONTH" ]]; then
        LOG_FILES=$(ls ${LOG}*)
        tar -czf ${LOG}.tar.gz ${LOG_FILES}
        RC=$? # Check whether an error occured
        if [[ "$RC" == "0" ]]; then
            rm ${LOG_FILES}
        fi
    fi
done
```

Note: This assumes that the first block of 8 digits is the datestamp, and everything after that is not relevant for which archive it is to go to.

**Update:**
The `sed` script no longer outputs files that do not contain a timestamp.

Comment: What do I need to do with the above solution if I want to separate the archive files by filename. Like App1YYYYMM and App2YYYYMM. At the moment it just grabs every log file based on YYYYMM.

Comment: If you try it you will find that it does just that.

Comment: Ah, I think I should have been more detailed in my explanation about the log files. Here is a sample of the format of the filenames. FailedAudit_20150101_000000.log  FailedAudit_20150209_000000.log  FailedAudit_20150316_000000.log  stats20150116.log  stats20150224.log
FailedAudit_20150102_000000.log  FailedAudit_20150210_000000.log  FailedAudit_20150317_000000.log  stats20150117.log  stats20150225.log
FailedAudit_20150103_000000.log 
As you can see there is underscore and . delimeters.

Comment: Have a look at the 3rd version of my script.

Comment: You are a king among kings. That worked like a champ. Thats amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, the script works for everything but this file type: server.log.YYYYMMDD. It is very different in format i suppose. It errors out like this: ./archive.sh: line 21: [[: er.log: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".log")

Comment: I think if I change it to `LOGTYPES=$(ls *.log*` it should catch the above server.log.YYYYMMDD files. i will test it to see

Comment: No it doesn't like that. Damn this is tricky. Maybe have to run a separate one for the server.log.YYYYMMDD ones.

Comment: Yes, that format is different. But the script should ignore these files. After all, it looks only for files that end in `.log`. But that's not the error you described. You have files in your directory that do not contain a datestamp, but end in `.log`. I hadn't anticipated that.

Comment: @Lawrence I have updated the script again, but to be honest, this starts to be a programming service for me, and Stackoverflow is not meant for that. Try to understand what the script is doing, and try to adapt it yourself.

Comment: For the meantime I just renamed all those `server.log.YYYYMMDD` files. Works well when all the log files have the same name pattern. Sorry I didnt mean for it to be a programming service. I tried to put a nested if statement in your script to specifically handle the server.log files, but ran into issue with it not separating the files when it does the tar job.

Comment: Yes I didn't state the different log file. It is not your fault. I am quite happy with your answer and will modify it in a way to cater for those files. I am considering putting this in the head of the script to rename the target files that don't match. `for file in server.log.*; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -e 's/.log./log/' -e 's/$/.log/')" ; done`

Answer (score -1):

here, not sure if workimg

```
#!/bin/bash
MONTH=$(date +%m)
OLDMONTH=$MONTH-1
for FILE in `ls $DIR`
do
    if [ ${FILE:-4:2} == $OLDMONTH]; then
        # do what you want with the file, it's one month old, eg add it to a list
    fi
done
# do what you want with the list, eg tar,...
```

run the script once a day as example with runwhen or cron

Comment: Actually, you have to declare month to be an integer variable. Otherwise, `$OLDMONTH` would be something like `08-1`, and it won't work. Secondly, even if it did work, `$OLDMONTH` would be something like `7`, not `07`, so it wouldn't fit the test. And thirdly, if you got that right, and you ran this script in January, it would compare files to something `00` instead of `12` as it should.

Comment: you're right, you should loop all files and month except this. you could run date with a specific date

Comment: Yes the problem is month is two digits. My approach is use find /DIR -name "App12015$OLDMONTH*.log | xargs tar rvf App12015$OLDMONTH.tar but not sure about the month problem

Comment: run date -d YYYYMMDD +"%y%m" and you get an integer that you can compare with test -gt (greater than) to date +"%y%m" (now)